# haskell postgresql-simple, how to access specific data from a broader query

Tags: postgresql, haskell, postgresql-simple

How can i access the data that`s in my query [VarcharIntDate] ?

```
data VarcharIntDate = VarcharIntDate {
  vc :: Maybe String,
  i  :: Maybe Int,
  d  :: Maybe Date
} deriving (Show)

instance FromRow VarcharIntDate where
  fromRow = VarcharIntDate <$> field <*> field <*> field
```

I understand how to print it, but I cant do much else with it because I don`t understand how to treat 'IO [VarcharIntDate]'

```
print =<< ( query_ conn "select vc,i,d from varintdate" :: IO [VarcharIntDate] )
```

but what I want to do is access 'd' from the n'th row of the returned [VarcharIntDate] or 'i' from all rows, so I can start pulling the data out  from the query and start working with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually already process the result of the `IO [VarcharIntDate]`. You use `=<<` with `print`. This is equivalent to:

```
main = do  -- or another function
    result <- query_ conn "select vc,i,d from varintdate" :: IO [VarcharIntDate]
    print result
```

You can process the result of `query_` by performing a `map`ping, or accessing the *n*-th element of the row like:

```
p = 2  -- sample p

main = do
    res <- query_ conn "select vc,i,d from varintdate" :: IO [VarcharIntDate]
    print (map i res)  -- print all i's
    print (d (res!!p)) -- print d of the p-th row
```

So here we can use `res!!p` to access the `p`-th row, and then call the `d` getter to obtain the `d` of that row.

If you want to obtain all `i`'s you can use `map i`.